# In javascript, how do I extract the month from date string "yyyy-mm-dd" or timeStamp?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a database with certain logged events as json objects, each one with it's own JS millisecond timestamp and also a date string in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", as well as a minutes entry.

I'd like to use either the timestamp or the date string, whichever is easier, as input into an algorithm which will count how many logs were entered in a given month.

I would also like the algorithm to sum the cumulative number of minutes were logged in a given month.

For example,

```
log1: {
Date:"2017-05-24",
TimeStamp:1495612800,
Minutes: 15},
log2: {
Date:"2017-05-19",
TimeStamp:1495180800,
Minutes: 45},
log3: {
Date:"2017-04-24",
TimeStamp:1493020800,
Minutes:30}
```

In this example, the algorithm would count that there are two logs in the month of May and one log in the month of April.

The algorithm would also return a sum of 60 minutes in the month of May and 30 minutes in the month of April.

Any help with parsing the input into the appropriate variables for counting would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the month from a single object it would be as simple as the following:

`var month = new Date(log1.TimeStamp * 1000).getMonth() +1` getMonth() is zero-based, so you need to add 1

To count the number of occurrences per month, you can do this:

```js
var logs = [{
    Date: "2017-05-24",
    TimeStamp: 1495612800,
    Minutes: 15
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-05-19",
    TimeStamp: 1495180800,
    Minutes: 45
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-04-24",
    TimeStamp: 1493020800,
    Minutes: 30
  }
];

var occurrences = logs.reduce(function (result, current) {
  // multiply unix timestamp by 1000 to get ms
  var date = new Date(current.TimeStamp * 1000);
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (!result[month]) {
    result[month] = {
      occurrences: 0,
      minutes: 0
    };
  }
  result[month].occurrences++;
  result[month].minutes += Number(current.Minutes);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(occurrences);
```

If you wanted to group the dates by year and then by month, it would require just a slight change to the code. It would look like the following:

```js
var logs = [{
    Date: "2017-05-24",
    TimeStamp: 1495612800,
    Minutes: 15
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-05-19",
    TimeStamp: 1495180800,
    Minutes: 45
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-04-24",
    TimeStamp: 1493020800,
    Minutes: 30
  }
];

var occurrences = logs.reduce(function(result, current) {
  // multiply unix timestamp by 1000 to get ms
  var date = new Date(current.TimeStamp * 1000);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  // make sure result[year] is defined
  if (!result[year]) { 
    result[year] = {};
  }
  // notice the original code below is now [year][month]
  if (!result[year][month]) {
    result[year][month] = {
      occurrences: 0,
      minutes: 0
    };
  }
  result[year][month].occurrences++;
  result[year][month].minutes += Number(current.Minutes);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(occurrences);
```

Comment: Hi mhodges, thanks for your help! This is most like what I was thinking about.  Actually, I have an add on to this question, but I don't know what forum would be the best to do it in, since this question and answer are nice and succinct.

Comment: @esd100 Feel free to ask another question, or if it is simple enough of a change, I can update my answer

Comment: I'll give it a shot in the comments. 
var logs = [{
    Date: "2017-05-24",
    TimeStamp: 1495612800,
    Minutes: 15
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-05-19",
    TimeStamp: 1495180800,
    Minutes: 45
  },
  {
    Date: "2017-04-24",
    TimeStamp: 1493020800,
    Minutes: 30
  }
];

Instead of counting the number of occurrences, the algorithm would return the cumulative number of minutes each month.

Comment: @esd100 Gotcha, yeah that's easy enough, let me edit my answer and I'll let you know.

Comment: @esd100 Okay, take a look. See if that does it for you. Just FYI, I left in the part about the number of occurrences because that is what the original question asked about.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I really appreciate the help. My algorithm skills are weak when it comes to dateTime concepts and it would have taken me hours to figure this out!

Comment: @esd100 Not a problem =) I think we've all been there at some point. That's why we're here to help!

Comment: @esd100 Edited my answer to include the year (as requested)

Answer (score 2):

> ### JavaScript getMonth() Method
>
> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

Use a function (note: you need convert UNIX timestamp to milliseconds so just time 1000 inside getMon function):

> UNIX timestamps are in seconds

```
function getMon(timestamp) {
  return (new Date(timestamp * 1000)).getMonth() + 1;
}
```

```js
var log1 = {Date: "2017-05-24",TimeStamp: 1495612800};
var log2 = {Date: "2017-05-19",TimeStamp: 1495180800};
var log3 = {Date: "2017-04-24",TimeStamp: 1493020800};

function getMon(timestamp) {
  return (new Date(timestamp * 1000)).getMonth() + 1;
}

console.log(getMon(log1['TimeStamp']));
console.log(getMon(log2['TimeStamp']));
console.log(getMon(log3['TimeStamp']));
```

Comment: How does this "count how many logs were entered in a given month."?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Date(miliseconds)` constructor will be the most robust approach, just in case the date format were to change.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> ```
> new Date(value);
> ```
>
> **value** Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix time stamp functions count in seconds).

```
var log1 = { Date: "2017-05-24", TimeStamp: 1495612800 };
var log1Date = new Date( log1.TimeStamp * 1000 );
log1Date.toLocaleString(); // "5/24/2017"
```

The `*1000` is because the `TimeStamp` value provided looks to be in seconds, but JavaScript requires a *mili*second value.

Comment: Actually, you end up with `"1/17/1970, 11:26:52 PM"`, don't forget to multiply the unix timestamp by 1000 to get milliseconds

Comment: How does this "count how many logs were entered in a given month."?

Comment: @mhodges The OP added that question to his posting after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the month number is already available in the *Date* property, there's no need to use a Date object:

```js
var logs = [
  {Date: "2017-05-24", TimeStamp: 1495612800, Minutes: 15},
  {Date: "2017-05-19", TimeStamp: 1495180800, Minutes: 45},
  { Date: "2017-04-24", TimeStamp: 1493020800, Minutes: 30}
];

var logMonthCount = logs.reduce(function(acc, log) {
  var month = log.Date.split('-')[1];
  acc[month] = acc[month]? acc[month]+1 : 1;
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(logMonthCount);
```

If using the *TimeStamp* property, it will be treated as UTC and converted to the local date based on the client timezone. So it may well be that for some logs within the timezone offset of the host from the start or end of the month, that the month in the *Date* property is a different month to that returned by `new Date(log.timeStamp*1000).getMonth()) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your timestamps, this should work:

```
var date = new Date(1495612800 * 1000);
var month = date.getMonth();
```

Then just implement a count against the result

Answer (score 0):

To get month as mm from yyyy-mm-dd you can simply:

```
log1.Date.substring(5, 7);
```

to get it as integer (without leading zeros):

```
parseInt(log1.Date.substring(5, 7));
```